# high-level 2D graphics development for an education iPad or Android app? (Processing? rokon?)

Tags: android, ios, rokon

I'm trying to help an education teacher, with a novice amount of programming experience (I know he's written Logo programs) write an iPad or Android app for education. (iPad would be better, since he has one). XCode / Objective C and OpenGL seem to have a very steep learning curve.

**Question**: What is the best high-level 2D development framework?

Some candidates might be Processing or rokon. Has anyone used either, and liked it? I started experimenting with rokon, and the physics was nice, but it still felt pretty low-level.

**Application**: The students would complete several puzzles, aiming to connect their visual and analytic skills. First, students would build a square out of "composite shapes" (which are built out of triangles) of different colors,

[image]

and then answer questions about the ratio of areas. For example, what is the ratio of the blue diamond to the entire square? Then, what is the ratio of the orange shape to the pink-red square? (Answers: 4/18, 6/2, by observing how each shape is built from green triangles).

Optimally, the students could drag the shapes around, and "snap" them together (rokon's physics seem suited for this task). Placing one shape on another might be more difficult, but would be nice (perhaps a "double tap to pick up" interface would work).

Answer (score 1):

For iOS [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) is an amazing framework.
For Android, I think Rokon is not being developed anymore. Take a look at [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/). It's not bad, has some quirks.

With either one you can create this sort of puzzle. I suppose however, the right one depends on your choice of platform, who will do most of the code? Does your friend have a Mac to run XCode on if they are going to write it?